# Use Prior Month - PHP Script

Tags: php

Below is a snippet of code that is part of a much bigger routine, although all I need assistance with is changing the code so it is uses the prior month, or the ability to define the month.

When this executes it adds data to MySQL based the current month, i.e. February but I need to have it also add data (once) for January.

Any help would be great.

```
$now = new DateTime('now');
$thisYear = $now->format("Y");
$thisMonth = $now->format('m');
$bookingsSql = str_replace('{check_in_year}', $thisYear, $bookingsSql);
$bookingsSql = str_replace('{check_in_month}', $thisMonth, $bookingsSql);
$bookingsSql = str_replace('{check_out_year}', $thisYear, $bookingsSql);
$bookingsSql = str_replace('{check_out_month}', $thisMonth, $bookingsSql);
$bookingsSql = str_replace('{close_date_year}', $thisYear, $bookingsSql);
$bookingsSql = str_replace('{close_date_month}', $thisMonth, $bookingsSql);
```

Comment: Why are you overwriting the same variable again and again ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran: looks like a simplistic templating system. replacing a bunch of `{foo}` template "vars" with year/date values.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify "last month" as your argument when creating your `DateTime` object.

```
$myDate = new DateTime ("last month");
print "Date: {$myDate->format("d")}, month: {$myDate->format("m")}\n";
// Output: Date: 14, month: 01
```

Alternatively, you can also use [`DateTime::sub()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php) to alter the date you have.

```
$myToday = new DateTime ();
$lastmonth = $myToday->sub (new DateInterval ('P1M'));
print "Last month: {$lastmonth->format("m")}\n";
// Output: Last month: 01
```

You can also define your own date if you like. See [the DateTime() manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php).

Comment: So if I change: $now = new DateTime('now'); to $now = new DateTime('last month'); the records will be created using January?

Comment: @user3308857 As the argument `last month` suggested, the `DateTime` object will be created using the month before current. If you run the script in February, then your records will start in January. If you run the script in August, your records will start in July.